# How to use executables/ DLLs from another folder/location in my Test Project?

Tags: .net, visual-studio-2010, deployment, dependencies

I am creating a test project in `Visual Studio 2010` for my existing project. I have added reference of one `DLL` that is being used in the project for which I am creating this test project.

Now problem is, after adding the reference of that DLL, when I am trying to execute the test, then I am getting a run time exception as

```
System.IO.FileNotFoundException: Could not load file or assembly 
'SOME NAME, Version=2.5.2.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=null' or one of its dependencies. The system cannot find the file specified
```

I have solved this issue by changing `Copy Local` attribute of that reference to True. But I dont want to change it to true. Because I dont want to make copy of this in test project's debug folder.

Is there any other way to do so?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is an **important question** I asked myself some years ago and found the following practical solution:

- put all application dll (to test) in `$root$\bin\Debug`
- put all your test dll in `$root$\bin`
- for each test dll or exe, have a `App.config` file that looks like the content below (note that I include in the probing paths, `.\Debug` of course, but also `.\NUnit\bin` because I put the NUnit assemblies there)

<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8" ?>
    <configuration>
      <runtime>
        <assemblyBinding xmlns="urn:schemas-microsoft-com:asm.v1">
          <probing privatePath="**Debug;NUnit\bin**" />
        </assemblyBinding>
      </runtime>
    </configuration>

[image]

Btw, just never use `Copy Local = true`, I wrote [white books](http://www.ndepend.com/WhiteBooks.aspx) on this topic (it can slow down compilation time up to **10 times**!)

Comment: Thank you so much. Mean while I found another way to refer DLL's from another directory in case of test projects. I am sharing that as an answer.

Comment: Does this work with .NETCore / .NET 6 ?

Answer (score 0):

When we talk about test projects in VS 2010. Then we have "Local.testsettings" file, automatically created in out test solution inside "solution items" directory.

For providing reference to executables/Dlls required in out test project we need to add their references as well as we need to modify this "Local.testsettings" file, if we dont want to create local copy of those ececutables/DLLs.

Now question is what to change in this file?
Double Click this "Local.testsettings" file in Visual Studio.
Go to "Unit Test" menu item.
Provide root folder for the assemblies to be loaded. (This can be any directory from where you want to use executables/ DLLs in our test project). 
Provide the same folder in the folders to use when the tests are run box using "Add folder" button.

Note:
To save this file you need to replace the previous one.
Click on "Apply" button.
Then click on "Save As" button, select the location of old "Local.testsettings" file and replace that file.

For me, in my test project, I am not creating local copy of any of my DLL's used in my test project. After changing "Local.testsettings" file, I can run my tests successfully.